# How do I use arrays in OpenAI function calling?

Tags: python, jsonschema, openai-api, json-schema-validator

I am using OpenAI's function calling to get a list of strings from a preset list of items. I want OpenAI to return values that belong only in the preset list and nothing else. [JSON schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html?highlight=enum#additional-items) states that I should use `{"items": false}` and include a "prefixItems" object. However, OpenAI's response comes as this:

400 {'error': {'message': ["Invalid schema for function 'get_something_work_related_that_is_redacted': In context=('properties', 'things'), array schema items is not an object"], 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}

I tried a different approach mentioned below, but still no bueno.

Here's the code:

```py
functions = [
        {
            "name": "get_something_work_related_that_is_redacted",
            "description": "Blah blah blah blah. The output must be from the enum of things given only and not self-generated.",
            "parameters": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "things": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "enum": [
                                "A",
                                "B",
                                "C",
                                "D",
                                "E",
                            ]
                        },
                    }
                },
                "required": ["datasets"]
            }
        }
    ]
```

Sometimes I get ["A", "C"] or something based on other parameters. But there are times I get ["A", "F"]. Some other times, I even get ["G", "H"]

Could anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

I've found there is not a way to force the usage of enums in functions. The model will just do what it wants half the time. The only thing you can do is validate the response.

As for the invalid schema, try this:

```
functions = [
 {
  "name": "get_something_work_related_that_is_redacted",
  "description": "Blah blah blah blah. The output must be from the enum of things given only and not self-generated.",
  "parameters": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "things": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "letters": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
]
```

I've also found that when you use an array type, it takes all array params as required. That could just be the model I'm using, and I'm hoping it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Someone graciously spent their time creating a draft 2020-12 JSON Schema of the [function calling schema](https://gist.github.com/jcxia43/6140df1b15950c50668a7117f5579188). I'm not sure if they correctly assumed all the pieces of it, but here it is and a sample payload following

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://platform.openai.com/schemas/function-calling",
  "$defs": {
    "objectWithProperties": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "array",
            "boolean",
            "integer",
            "null",
            "number",
            "object",
            "string"
          ]
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "type",
            "required",
            "properties"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": [
                "object"
              ]
            },
            "required": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "properties": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/propertiesObject"
            }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false
        },
        "enum": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "items": {
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/objectWithProperties"
            },
            {
              "type": "string"
            }
          ]
        },
        "required": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "properties": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/propertiesObject"
        },
        "$ref": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "propertiesObject": {
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
        ".*": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/objectWithProperties"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "name",
    "description",
    "parameters"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "parameters": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "type",
        "required",
        "properties"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "object"
          ]
        },
        "required": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "properties": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/propertiesObject"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

```json
{
    "name": "stack-test-openai",
    "description": "a sample json function call instance for the OpenAI JSON Schema",
    "parameters": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "stack": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                    "A",
                    "B",
                    "C",
                    "D",
                    "E",
                    "F"
                ]
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "stack"
        ]
    }
}
```

If you want to enable this schema validation in your Monaco based editor, such as VS Code, you can add this to your `settings.json` and it will automatically start to work. I've arbitrarily defined the `$id` and the `fileMatch` value, these are not official OpenAI values.

###### settings.json

```json
"json.schemas": [
    {
      "fileMatch": [
        "*.openai.json"
      ],
      "schema": {
        "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
        "$id": "https://platform.openai.com/schemas/function-calling",
        "$defs": {
          "objectWithProperties": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "array",
                  "boolean",
                  "integer",
                  "null",
                  "number",
                  "object",
                  "string"
                ]
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "description": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "parameters": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                  "type",
                  "required",
                  "properties"
                ],
                "properties": {
                  "type": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                      "object"
                    ]
                  },
                  "required": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  },
                  "properties": {
                    "$ref": "#/$defs/propertiesObject"
                  }
                },
                "additionalProperties": false
              },
              "enum": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "items": {
                "oneOf": [
                  {
                    "$ref": "#/$defs/objectWithProperties"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "required": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "properties": {
                "$ref": "#/$defs/propertiesObject"
              },
              "$ref": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
          },
          "propertiesObject": {
            "type": "object",
            "patternProperties": {
              ".*": {
                "$ref": "#/$defs/objectWithProperties"
              }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
          }
        },
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "name",
          "description",
          "parameters"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "parameters": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
              "type",
              "required",
              "properties"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "object"
                ]
              },
              "required": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "properties": {
                "$ref": "#/$defs/propertiesObject"
              }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  ]
```

---

Regarding your actual question, you can define an `enum` of strings for a single property as shown in the example instance.